# imagen de fondo no se ve completa -

Tags: css, imagen

Hola tengo el siguiente problema tengo la siguiente pagina : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven el problema es que no se ve completamente la imagen (el titulo de la pagina de la imagen donde dice rancho rosa susana comento) ,la imagen esta correctamente se adpata a las diferentes pantallas pero mi problema es es que no se ve completa alguien sabe porque?

este es mi codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Rosa Susana</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Logo para web.svg" />
  <style type="text/css">
  
body{
background: url(inicio.png) no-repeat center center fixed ;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}











#header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<!--
<div class="container">
    <a href="inicio.html">
<img class="img-responsive" src="inicio.jpg" >

</div>-->

<div id="header" onclick="location.href='inicio.html'"></div>



<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Rancho-Rosa-Susana-193044927891849/
" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook
  </a><br><br>
   <a style="background:red;border:none;" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB41yyo-wrldZQchu_tM3dA" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-youtube"></span>  Youtube
  </a><br>
</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no y si me acuerdo de la pregunta que comentastes pero no es sobre eso.

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve] en el que se pueda ver el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica generalmente en la altura de la imagen, puesto que aunque adaptes el ancho de tu imagen a la ventana, este intentara conservar la proporción «Si es un rectángulo, tratara de mantenerse como un rectángulo» Lo que puedes hacer es definir que no respete esa relación y que se adapte tanto al ancho como al alto, sin embargo debes tener en cuenta que entre mas angosta sea la ventana se visualizara mas achatado puesto que el alto se mantiene, algo así:

```css
html {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
body{
  width:100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.365imagenesbonitas.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/fondos-halloween-mano.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: La solución que presentas podría provocar deformaciones de la imagen en distintas pantallas/resoluciones.

Comment: Claro, así lo mencione: "... debes tener en cuenta que entre mas angosta sea la ventana se visualizara mas achatado puesto que el alto se mantiene", intentaba unicamente explicarle el porque la situación de su imagen resumiendo que su problema era la relación de aspecto.